# how to check password field with confirm password field

Tags: javascript, html

I have written a function in javascript to chek whether both fields are same or not:
javascript code:

```
function validate();{
var x= getElementByName("password");
var y= getElementByName("retype_password");
if(x==y) return;
else alert("password not same");
```

HTML code: HOW CAN I CALL THE ABOVE WRITTEN FUNCTION IN THE HTML CODE

```
password : <input type= "password" name="password"> <br><br>
retype password : <input type="password" name="retype_password" > <br><br>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Comment: You need to compare the values of both inputs, not the inputs themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
password : <input type= "password" id="password" onblur="validate()"> <br><br>
retype password : <input type="password" id="retype_password"  onblur="validate()"> <br><br>

<script>
function validate() {
var x= document.getElementById("password");
    var y= document.getElementById("retype_password");
if(x.value==y.value) return;
else alert("password not same");
}
</script>
```

Comment: I don't want to add a button, I WANT TO CHECK IT DYNAMICALLY

Comment: I just edited to do the validation when the textboxes lose focus

Answer (score 2):

Please be careful with method names in JavaScript. The correct method for picking the element by name is `document.getElementsByName` which returns a `NodeList`. So in order to get the first field with the required name you should treat the result as array:

```
function validate() {
    var x = document.getElementsByName('password')[0].value,
        y = document.getElementsByName('retype_password')[0].value;

    if (x === y) {
        return true;
    }

    alert('password not same');
    return false;
}
```

To make the solution work correctly you have to bind the validation function as a `<form>` *submit* event (as an example):

```
var form = document.getElementById('myform');
form.addEventListener('submit', function() {
    return validate();
}, false);
```

Or shorter as:

```
document.getElementById('myform').addEventListener('submit', validate, false);
```

If you don't have a form and use some button-like elements, you may bind a *click* event, e.g.:

```
var mybutton = document.getElementById('mybutton');
mybutton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if ( validate() ) {
        // do AJAX request or whatever...
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, they want to know how to call the function.. Like on form submit

Comment: @VisioN : You correct the JS function, but to me you don't answer the question

Comment: The code is good. But he want to know how he can call it. I think he should add a `onclick="validate(event);"` attribute on the submit button. (if validate return false, prevent the event from bubbling with `event.preventDefault();`). So you should add event as an attribute for validate.

Comment: Apolo, write that as an answer.  That's what he's looking for, I think.  Though the additions/changes by VisioN need to be there, too.

Comment: @Apolo I don't want to add a button to confirm the password.

Comment: @Helpful I would rather suggest to bind a form submit event instead.

Comment: @new_stacky if you have inputs, you have a form. If you have a form you have a `<input type="submit">` button =)

Comment: see my answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983479/how-to-check-password-field-with-confirm-password-field/22983671#22983671

Comment: @apolo ,According to you the passwords will be checked while submitting the form, I want to check them dynamically.

Comment: you can bind it with input event like onFocusOut it's up to you. I'm just showing you how to bind it to an event, you can choose what kind of events you need.

Answer (score 1):

Their are many ways to call this function.

You can add a new button :

```
<input type = 'button' value = 'validate' onclick = 'validate()' />
```

Or call the function when the focus on the text field is out :

```
<input type="password" name="retype_password" onblur = 'validate()'  > <br><br>
```

Their are other ways to do (onkeydown, onchange...) check JS events to learn more : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp

Answer (score 0):

You have to use getElementById instead of getElementByName
**Javascript:**

```
function validate() {
    var x = getElementById("password").value;
    var y = getElementById("retype_password").value;
    if(x==y) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("password not same");
        return false;
    }
}
```

**and html:**

```
<form onsubmit="return validate();"  action="submit_path" >
    <input type= "password" id="password" name="password">
    <input type= "password" id="retype_password" name="retype_password">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Right code from @VisioN :

```
function validate(event) {
    var x = document.getElementsByName('password')[0].value,
        y = document.getElementsByName('retype_password')[0].value;

    if (x === y) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert('password not same');
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Add a `onclick="validate(event);"` attribute on the submit button.
(if validate return false, prevent the event from bubbling with event.preventDefault();).

---

**EDIT**

Maybe it is better tyo bind it to onSubmit event.
`<form onsubmit="validate(event)">`

Apolo

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easier way by using class:

```
password : <input type= "password" class="passwords" name="password"> <br><br>
retype password : <input type="password" class="passwords" name="retype_password" > <br><br>
```

In your javascript:

```
var passwords = document.getElementsByClassName("passwords");

function validate(){
var first = passwords[0].value;
var second = passwords[1].value;

   if(first != second){
      //Invalid
   } else{
      //Valid
   }
}
```